# How to start IPython with sudo

Tags: python, sudo

How do I start IPython using `sudo`? 
So e.g. when I do

```
sudo optirun ipython
```

it says

```
[40475.566816] [ERROR]Error running "ipython": No such file or directory
```

I know it sounds a bit crazy but I'm running switchable Nvidia graphics with bumblebee and need to import a certain library within IPython that needs to access the gpu. I dug around and get permission errors within other IDEs like Spyder which leads me to believe `sudo` with make my problems go away.

Comment: Totally unrelated but you should probably be using primusrun, not optirun in a modern environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have Nvidia graphics drivers so I can't fully test this, but some ideas:

Have you tried just

```
sudo ipython
```

to see if optirun might not be the problem? "sudo ipython" works fine on my system.

Also try:

```
sudo optirun /path/to/ipython
```

So on my system this would be:

```
sudo optirun /usr/bin/ipython
```